# Javascript datetime to date

Tags: javascript, date

i have the following date format:

```
2014-07-08 00:00:00
```

i wish to convert it into

```
2014-07-08
```

I have been looking all over the World wide web to find examples but couldn't find a solution?

Doesnt javascript have a way to format a datetime into a date string?

Comment: No, JavaScript does not have built-in date formatting, but the [Date API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) provides access to all the parts of a date, so creating any format you like is pretty easy.

Comment: How about just splitting the original format on a space. Like: `"2014-07-08 00:00:00".split(" ")[0]`

Comment: If you can depend on the format, use string.substring(0,10);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
var input  = '2014-07-08 00:00:00',
    output = input.split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply split?

```
date="2014-07-08 00:00:00".split(" ")[0];
```

Or if you are looking for more complex operations on dates, I would use [moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date('2014-07-08 00:00:00')
d.toDateString()
```

This will give 
Thu Aug 07 2014
If this is not enough. You may consider using moment.js from http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PeteA/kr11waha/1/

Based on an answer I gave earlier:

```
function addZero(v) {
    if (v < 10) return '0' + v;
    return v;
}

function stripDate(ds) {
    var d = new Date(ds),
        y = d.getFullYear(),
        m = addZero(d.getMonth() + 1),
    d = addZero(d.getDate());

    return y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
}

stripDate('2014-07-08 00:00:00');
```